# How access nested elements with repeated class xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I need access a nested element with repeated class, like that:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="first">
        <div class="second"></div>
        <div class="second">
            <p>I need that text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So i try something like that:

```
$localizacao_x = $xpath_det_page->query('//div[@class="container"]/div[@class="first"][3]/div[@class="second"][2]/p');
$localizacao = $localizacao_x->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo "[Localizacao] : [".$localizacao."]"."<br/>";
```

But result in non object, any tip?

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath seems to be correct. I tested

```
//div[@class="container"]/div[@class="first"][3]/div[@class="second"][2]/p
```

which result is

> I need that text